# Problema en consulta MAX()

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT MAX(facturaNumero) AS UltimoNum, 
               MAX(facturaNumero) + 1 AS SiguienteNum, 
               FacturaLetra, TipoDeComprobante, Estado, 
               Anulada 
FROM comprobantes 
WHERE FacturaLetra='A' 
AND TipoDeComprobante='FCEFACTURA' 
AND Estado='ACTIVA' 
AND Anulada='NOANULADA'
```

Necesito que me devuelva un número siguiente al último número obtenido de la tabla.
El problema es que siempre me muestra "9" como último número obtenido y no es correcto. Con ese criterio hay 15 registros.

**Nueva prueba**
Probé colocando en los registros del 1 al 9 un cero delante. Es decir, dos dígitos. 01, 02, 03, etc... y así funciona. 
El problema es que no puedo utilizar el 0 delante en los primeros 9 valores.

Comment: Por las condiciones se me ocurre que ese 9 es el  número más alto que las satisface.

Comment: Es raro eso, porque con otro valor en TipoDeComprobante, funciona correctamente

Comment: Quizás estás sacando el MAX a una cadena en lugar de un número?

Comment: Lo mejor es que agregues la estructura de la tabla y parte de los datos para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Va salir otro dato con TipoDeComprobante porque si satisface con ese valor, después de todo, para eso son las condiciones

Comment: Probé colocando en los registros del 1 al 9 un cero delante. Es decir, dos dígitos. 01, 02, 03, etc... y así funciona.
El problema es que no puedo utilizar el 0 delante en los primeros 9 valores.
Alguna sugerencia para resolverlo?

Comment: Fijate el tipo de dato de esa columna

Comment: Perfecto! Esa es la solución! El tipo de dato era VARCHAR, lo cambié a DECIMAL y funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Pero una pregunta, ¿la columna en cuestión es `facturaNumero`? **¿Qué guarda esa columna?** Según **su nombre** guarda números de factura, si es así, no es correcto que le des un tipo de dato `VARCHAR` ni tampoco `DECIMAL`, sino que debería ser del tipo `INT`. Ahora bien, si guarda valores monetarios sí debería ser `DECIMAL`. Hila muy fino asignado tus tipos de datos, para que no te encuentres con sorpresas como la ya expuesta en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano siempre tan preciso en tus respuestas y explicaciones. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Yo te sugiero que uses mejor una tabla de parámetros para asegurar que se obtienen valores únicos en el caso de que varios clientes usen el programa al mismo tiempo.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `next_folio`( _id int ) RETURNS int(10) unsigned
BEGIN

    declare cnext integer unsigned default 0;

    # Folio ventas temporales
    if _id = 8 then
      UPDATE params SET folio=LAST_INSERT_ID( folio + 1 )
      where par_id = 'TMP';
      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into cnext;
      #Check if null or 0
      if ( cnext = 0 ) or ( isnull(cnext) ) then
        set cnext = 1;
        update params set foli = cnext
        where par_id = 'TMP';
      end if;
    end if;

    return cnext;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

La misma función podría regresarte los ids con ceros a la izquierda o como los necesites.

Saludos!